# Spotlight icon started flickering constantly

Tags: high-sierra, spotlight, icon, menu-bar

I'm running High Sierra 10.13.3 on a 15" rMBP, with Alfred v3.8.2 as my Spotlight alternative. I haven't used Spotlight for years, and I honestly can't remember if the icon was always there or not there at all before.

For the past week or so my Spotlight icon has started to flicker on and off like this all the time:

[image]

It's super-distracting..

I haven't installed any new software in this time, or done anything to my system config, so I've no idea what could have suddenly caused this. I tried installed the latest Alfred update after the issue appeared to see if that would help, but it hasn't.

I've tried searching online for a solution but they all seem to be years old solutions for older versions of MacOS, and haven't helped. Things I've tried:

1. Fixing permissions on my primary HD.
2. Adding then removing my HD from the excluded list in Spotlight prefs.
3. Re-arranging my menu bar icons and rebooting my system.
4. Deleting `com.apple.systemuiserver.plist` and reboot, it successfully lost all of my menu bar preferences, (display bluetooth icon, show date and time etc.) but the problem persists.

Other suggestions involved reinstalling my system, which I'm not willing to do for a little icon annoyance; I'd rather just stick some tape over that part of the screen, but that's obviously not ideal.

Any help gratefully received. Please save my sanity.